# Apply filter buttons to columns when creating a new workbook through VBA

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

So I have a data set that I scan and VBA creates a new workbook with the desired data in it.

This works fine, all I'm trying to do is that when the new workbook is created, VBA also loads/applies the filter buttons to each header cell in the new workbook.

When I send the new workbook out to the intended party I want it to already have the filter buttons in the header cells so that they don't have to add them themselves.

Any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Range.AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) with no parameters; from the docs:

> If you omit all the arguments, this method simply toggles the display of the AutoFilter drop-down arrows in the specified range.

```
Workbooks("YourWorkbook").Worksheets("YourSheet").Range("A1:G100").AutoFilter
```